How do I change Facebook access on page from partial to full?
I have Full Facebook Access over a page of a company. I have added another person as administrator to Facebook page of a company, but while adding access I gave them Partial access. Now I'd like to promote them to Full Facebook access. Is this even possible? When I go to Settings > Page Setup > Page Access and then click three dots on another user then I see only Delete option. Here is an article I found on this subject: https://www.facebook.com/help/187316341316631/ . It has the following options: "Give Facebook access", "Give Task Access", "Edit Task Access" and "Remove Facebook or Task access", but I need to know how to edit Facebook access on page of someone from Partial to Full (to allow them to add users)
